# What kind of residuals and Cook's distance are used for GLM?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, cooks-distance

Does anybody know what the formula for Cook's distance is? The original Cook's distance formula uses studentized residuals, but why is R using std. Pearson residuals when computing the Cook's distance plot for a GLM. I know that studentized residuals are not defined for GLMs, but how does the formula to compute Cook's distance look like?

Assume the following example:

```
numberofdrugs <- rcauchy(84, 10)
healthvalue <- rpois(84,75)
test <- glm(healthvalue ~ numberofdrugs, family=poisson)
plot(test, which=5)
```

What is the formula for Cook's distance? In other words, what is the formula to compute the red dashed line? And where does this formula for standardized Pearson residuals come from?

[image: cook's distance]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you take a look at the code (simple type `plot.lm`, without parenthesis, or `edit(plot.lm)` at the R prompt), you'll see that [Cook's distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance) are defined line 44, with the `cooks.distance()` function. To see what it does, type `stats:::cooks.distance.glm` at the R prompt. There you see that it is defined as

```
(res/(1 - hat))^2 * hat/(dispersion * p)
```

where `res` are Pearson residuals (as returned by the `influence()` function), `hat` is the [hat matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_matrix), `p` is the number of parameters in the model, and `dispersion` is the dispersion considered for the current model (fixed at one for logistic and Poisson regression, see `help(glm)`). In sum, it is computed as a function of the leverage of the observations and their standardized residuals.
(Compare with `stats:::cooks.distance.lm`.)

For a more formal reference you can follow references in the `plot.lm()` function, namely

> Belsley, D. A., Kuh, E. and Welsch, R.
>   E. (1980). *Regression Diagnostics*.
>   New York: Wiley.

Moreover, about the additional information displayed in the graphics, we can look further and see that R uses

```
plot(xx, rsp, ...                    # line 230
panel(xx, rsp, ...)                  # line 233
cl.h <- sqrt(crit * p * (1 - hh)/hh) # line 243
lines(hh, cl.h, lty = 2, col = 2)    #
lines(hh, -cl.h, lty = 2, col = 2)   #
```

where `rsp` is labeled as Std. Pearson resid. in case of a GLM, Std. residuals otherwise (line 172); in both cases, however, the formula used by R is (lines 175 and 178)

```
residuals(x, "pearson") / s * sqrt(1 - hii)
```

where `hii` is the hat matrix returned by the generic function `lm.influence()`. This is the usual formula for std. residuals:

$$rs_j=\frac{r_j}{\sqrt{1-\hat h_j}}$$

where $j$ here denotes the $j$th covariate of interest. See e.g., Agresti *Categorical Data Analysis*, §4.5.5.

The next lines of R code draw a smoother for Cook's distance (`add.smooth=TRUE` in `plot.lm()` by default, see `getOption("add.smooth")`) and contour lines (not visible in your plot) for critical standardized residuals (see the `cook.levels=` option).